# How do i replace IN clause with JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cursor

```
select [CLIENT_SUIT_ID]
  ,[CLIENT_CODE]
  ,[CARD_ID]
  ,[EXPIRE_DATE]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by CARD_ID order by CARD_ID ASC)
from [KSS_TMP].[dbo].[CLIENT_SUIT]
where CARD_ID in(
SELECT CARD_ID
    from [KSS_TMP].[dbo].[CLIENT_SUIT]
    where CLIENT_CODE NOT LIKE '080%' AND card_id != '-'
    GROUP BY CARD_ID
    HAVING COUNT(CARD_ID) > 1
    )
```

Can you tell me how to replace IN clause with JOIN.I tried to keep my conditions so i have to use IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace your `in` clause with a `join`:

```
select [CLIENT_SUIT_ID]
  ,[CLIENT_CODE]
  ,[CARD_ID]
  ,[EXPIRE_DATE]
  ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by CARD_ID order by CARD_ID ASC)
from [KSS_TMP].[dbo].[CLIENT_SUIT] as Tab1 JOIN 
    (SELECT CARD_ID FROM [KSS_TMP].[dbo].[CLIENT_SUIT] 
     where CLIENT_CODE NOT LIKE '080%' AND card_id != '-' 
     GROUP BY CARD_ID 
     HAVING COUNT(CARD_ID) > 1 ) as Tab2 ON Tab1.Card_Id = Tab2.Card_Id
```

---

In your case, you don't really need the extra subquery.  You could do it all in 1 query using another window function with `conditional aggregation`:

```
select * from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by card_id order by card_id) rn,
    count(case when client_code not like '080%' and card_id != '-' 
               then 1 end) over (partition by card_id) cnt
  from client_suit
  ) t
where t.cnt > 1;
```